# How can I login to HTML login page with my email address in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I create a HTML login page and I authenticate it through `views.py`. I want to login with my email address only. But when I use other email addresses , I can able to login.I set custom_authentication in my `views.py`.

Template login.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>S.P.M School</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 0px solid black;
}
</style>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var mail = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var psd = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
    var atpos = mail.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = mail.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=mail.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;

   }
if (psd == null || psd == "") {
        alert("Not a valid Password");
        return false;
    }

}


</script>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="section">

 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
{% endif %}

      <div class="headline">
      <font size="10": color="white"><center>S.P.M.L.P School</center></font>
      </div>


      <span>303nishanth@gmail.com <br />
      <br />
      +91 9961685892</span> </div>

    <ul>
      <li class="#"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'event' %}">Event</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'calendar' %}">School Calendar</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>

<br><br>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">


    <div id="section"><br><br>
      <h1><center>Login As<font color="red"> Admin</font></center></h1><br>
       </div>

         <form name="myForm" action="{% url 'class_info' %}" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">




        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='wu5eSIDElr8EsVDgXmHmFNCCmSLdhyK5' />
         {%csrf_token%}


     <div class="text">
        <p><center><input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="Username or Email"></p></center>
        <p><center><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p></center>
        <p class="remember_me">




        </p>
        <center><p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p></center>
      </form>
    </div>


  </section>


</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/login.html')

def custom_auth(username=None, password=None):
    user = None
    if username == '303nishanth@gmail.com': # only this email is allowed
       user = authenticate(username=email, password=psd)
    return user

def login_submit(request):
    context = {}

    email = request.POST.get('email','')
    psd = request.POST.get('password', '')

    user = custom_auth(username=email, password=psd)
    if user is not None:
        # the password verified for the user
            if user.is_active:
                context['message'] = "User is valid, active and authenticated"
                return render (request,'class_info.html',context)   
            else:
                    context['message']= "The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!"
    else:
        # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
            context['message']= "The username and password were incorrect."

    return render (request,'login.html',context)
```

Comment: Please show your `urls.py`

Comment: url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^login_submit/$', views.login_submit, name='login_submit'),

Comment: So what is `action="{% url 'class_info' %}"` in yout html supposed to do?

Comment: I want to login to the page class_info.html. So i set the action on to that page